# Determining the sample sample size in Clara (Clarans)

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have a relatively large data set. I want to use clara for clustering. However, the results of clara depend on the sample size. So, the goal is not only to determine the number of clusters but also the right sample size. I know one package where I can "tune" the calra application.

```
libary(factoextra)

fviz_nbclust(scale(mtcars), 
             FUNcluster = clara, 
             method = "wss", 
             k.max = 6)
```

If I understand the concept correctly setting `samplesize` > 1 converts clara into clarans.

```
fviz_nbclust(scale(mtcars), 
             FUNcluster = clara, 
             method = "wss", 
             k.max = 6, 
             samplesize = 2)
```

Any Idea how to get the right sample size for clara(ns)?

Answer (score 0):

As large as you can afford.

I doubt that choosing sample size >1 makes that CLARANS, because they are fairly different if I recall correctly. But if you sample the entire database, CLARA becomes PAM by definition.

There was recently a paper introducing faster versions of PAM, CLARA, CLARANS. Make sure to use the faster versions...